# How can I know what stocks in Shanghai Stock Exchange use Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I typed:

```
FinancialData["ss:600050", {2013, 11, 20}]
```

but returns:
 ss:600050 is not a known entity, class, or tag for FinancialData. Use FinancialData[] for a list of entities.

Answer (score 1):

```
Union@StringCases[FinancialData["Stocks"], "SS:" ~~ b__ -> b]
```

gives you a long list of available stocks